# How to use php session in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I use php session in drupal 6 and store value such as $_SESSION['title'] = 'something'; and want to get store value as $_SESSION['title'];. But i can not get any value. What is the problem in my code snippet or please give me the process of using php session in drupal 6.

Comment: Are you trying to use `$_SESSION` with an anonymous user?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110376/how-does-one-store-and-retrieve-custom-session-variables-in-drupal-6

Comment: Thanks for your help and this is the correct solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the PHP session handler?

> [PHP Runtime Configuration - Session Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

These settings are configured in the `[Session]` section of your `php.ini` configuration file.